# Task Manager Affinity in Flink

Tags: apache-flink

We need to run 10 jobs on a Flink cluster, 4 out of them are not CPU bound, so for them, we can have 2xcpu task slots, however, 6 jobs are CPU bound and they need heavy CPU i.e vpcu/2 slots on each task manager. My question is how can I tell Flink that use x machines(task managers) for this job and y task managers for another one. Do I need to have a separate cluster for CPU bound jobs or is there any way to achieve this in a single cluster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you will need to have a separate cluster for this. [FLIP-169:  DataStream API for Fine-Grained Resource Requirements](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/x/MI3OCg), coming in Flink 1.14, may better support this use case.